# Could not find a matching version of package

Tags: magento2.3, composer, github

I have uploaded my magento 2 module to **GitHub**, and published my private module to https://packagist.com/. Now module published successfully as below.

[image]

And my composer as below

```
{
    "name": "vlcsolutions/module-connector",
    "description": "Business Central Express Connect",
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.0.0|~7.1.0|~7.2.0|~7.3.0|~7.4.0"
    },"minimum-stability": "dev-main",
"repositories": {
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://repo.packagist.com/vlcsolutions/"
},
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "2.2.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "vlcsolutions\\connector\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

When I installing `composer require vlcsolutions/module-connector:dev-stable` the module getting below error.

[image]

Can you please suggest me where I went wrong?

Comment: what happened if you remove `:dev-stable` ?

Comment: @fmsthird Getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the `composer.json` has a `"version": "2.2.0"`.  Which is not listed in your available package version.
Maybe try changing it to `dev` or `dev-stable` and try again.

Comment: Tried the both `dev-stable` and `dev-main` versions. See my updated thread. And I have a verion `2.2.0`.

Comment: hmmmm, have you checked this one ? https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a release in Github? From your repository, click "Tags" towards the top of the page, then "Create a Release" and fill out the release version as 2.2.0.

Comment: Created, but still getting same error.

Comment: is it a private github repository? if so you'll need to specify the git repo as a vcs source in composer.json and add your composer client ssh keys to the git repo - https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories

Comment: Okay, let me check